# Solresol Words to Array in js Using Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

Solresol is a language where every word is made up of musical **notes** **(do, re, mi, fa, sol, la, si)**. I have a dictionary of English words and their Solresol translations (Ex: `{ "Climb" : "Sollasi" }`), but I'd like to get each individual note in the word rather than the whole word.

For example I'd like to change the **string** `"Sollasi"` to the **array** `["sol", "la", "si"]`. I'm not very good with regexes so here is what I have right now in JavaScript:

```
input.split(/(do)|(re)|(mi)|(fa)|(sol)|(la)|(si)/)
```

This regex isn't working, so I was wondering if someone could help me come up with a better one.

Comment: Er ... where does "sol" come from?  Or should your array be (do, re, mi, fa, so**l**, la, si)?

Comment: Edited. Sorry that was a typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a positive lookahead:

```js
const input = 'solresol';
const output = input.split(/(?=do|re|mi|fa|sol|la|si)/i);

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 2):

instead of split try match like this

```js
console.log("Sollasi".match(/do|re|mi|fa|sol|la|si/ig))
```